# How to pass initial state with Next.js Router.push?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, recharts

I have an `onClick` event handler that fires when a data point on a graph is clicked. There are two curves on the graph, and depending on the curve clicked I want the child component to have an initial state set. For example, click on `curve1` and have that set as initial state in the next component, and likewise for `curve2`.

Using `recharts` I render several `Line` components with the `onClick` handler in the `activeDot` prop:

```js
<Line
    name={properties.prettyName}
    isAnimationActive={true}
    activeDot={{
        onClick: (data) =>
            changeURLView(data)
    }}
    type="linear"
    key={properties.key}
    dataKey={properties.dataKey}
    stroke={properties.color}
/>
```

And the `changeURLViewScan` handler:

```html
const changeURLView = (data) => {
// I can check which curve the datapoint belongs to here
        const sID: string = data.payload.id
        

        router.push(
            '/p/[pID]/s/[sID]',
            router.asPath + `/s/${sID}`
        )
    }
```

React Router has a `generatePath` function which allows you to pass props on to the next component, however I don't see something that will accomplish this with Next.js.

`Next/Router` does let you pass query parameters, but I don't want that in the URL. I want to be able to click on a curve and have the next component's initial state already populate depending on the curve clicked. I might be able to have a prop `initialCurveState` and set the component state that way, however  the issue remains - how do I pass a prop or set initial state using Next.js?